# Format PHP array dynamic Years

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Wondering if someone may know a way to do this easily.

I am working on an JSON API,I have a set of years looped into an array like below.

```
$years =[];
for ($x = date('Y'); $x <= date('Y') + 9; $x++) {
  $years[$x] = $x;
}
```

**JSON output:**

```
{


  "2017": "2017",
   "2018": 2018,
   "2019": 2019,
   "2020": 2020,
   "2021": 2021,
   "2022": 2022,
   "2023": 2023,
   "2024": 2024,
   "2025": 2025,
   "2026": 2026
}
```

How can I change this so I can map an ID and Year into its own sub-array.

(eg. So the output would be something like.

```
{
"years": [
      {
         "id": 1,
         "year": "2014"
      },
      {
         "id": 2,
         "year": "2015"
      }
   ]
```

Any help or suggestion would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
for ($i=0; $i < 9; $i++) {
  $years[] = ['id'=> $i+1, 'year' => date('Y') + $i];
}
```

However, why store the id in a separate index?

```
for ($i=0; $i < 9; $i++) {
  $years[] = date('Y') + $i;
}
```

To finalize the array you can do:

```
echo json_encode(['years' => $years]);
```

Comment: Hey thanks. Didn't think of doing it this way. First one worked perfect. Thank  you.